# How to get return status of a command in subshell into the main shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to retrieve the return status of a command which is being executed in a subshell.

I am running the below script from Unix Box `A` which has a passwordless SSH access to Box `B` whose IP is mentioned in the script as `ip_addr`.

I want to get the return status of command which is ran in subshell in my current environment.

That is if the below command fails:

```
echo "cmd" | system_program> 2>> /dev/null
```

then `echo $?` should print non-zero value and I should be able to use that value to decide further action.

Snippet of my script is:

**sample.sh** :

```
ip_addr="xxx.xxx.xx.xx"

status=$(ssh -q -T $ip_addr << EOF
rm /tmp/program.log; echo "cmd" | system_program> 2>> /dev/null; echo $?
EOF
)
```

Comment: Basically, if a command being executed in subshell fails,then its return status(which should be non-zero),should be available to its parent shell.

Comment: I get status = 0 which is the status of last executed command in parent shell. I cross checked the same by failing a command prior to the calling of the subshell.
In that case ,the status was set to non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the here-doc, or the echo. Try:

```
ssh -q -T $ip_addr 'rm /tmp/program.log; echo "cmd" | system_program> 2>> /dev/null'
```

Or if you want to use here-doc set errexit:

```
status=$(ssh -q -T $ip_addr << EOF
set -o errexit
rm /tmp/program.log; echo "cmd" | system_program> 2>> /dev/null
EOF
)
```